# Specifying a MAC address of a new virtual machine instance on Google Cloud

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, mac

We are planning to move a Windows 2012 Server to Google Cloud, but we have one issue. We are going to reinstall on this server an application that uses the server’s MAC address for its licensing so we have to maintain the MAC address of the old server. Can we specify the MAC address of the new server during the deploying of the preconfigured image on the Google cloud?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently customizing MAC address is **not supported** in Google Cloud Platform VMs and thus it can not be specified during the deployment. However, there is an [open feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/78084918) for it in the Google Cloud Public Issue Tracker.

I would recommend anyone who has similar request to [star the feature request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) to ensure that they receive updates about it and post comments to attract more attention to it.